Running solala rpc node get connection timeout
os : ubuntu 22.04
solnala version: solana-cli 1.18.21 (src:818807a5; feat:4215500110, client:SolanaLabs)
validator_sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
export RUST_LOG=error

solana-validator \
    --identity /var/solana/data/config/validator-keypair.json \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --no-voting \
    --ledger /var/solana/data/ledger \
    --accounts /var/solana/accounts \
    --log /home/r630/solana-rpc.log \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --rpc-bind-address 127.0.0.1 \
    --private-rpc \
        --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --init-complete-file /var/solana/data/init-completed \
    --limit-ledger-size \

then start script
./validator.sh

got error
>cat solana-rpc.log
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 199.96.63.163:8001, connection timed out
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 199.96.63.163:8001: connection timed out
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 114.43.24.59:8001, connection timed out
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 185.45.7.165:8001, connection timed out
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 202.160.128.14:8001, connection timed out
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 199.59.150.40:8001, connection timed out
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 202.160.128.210:8001, connection timed out
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 199.59.150.40:8001: connection timed out
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 114.43.24.59:8001: connection timed out
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 202.160.128.14:8001: connection timed out
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 202.160.128.210:8001: connection timed out
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 185.45.7.165:8001: connection timed out
Unable to determine the validator's public IP address


I'd like to know how to resolve this problem.

Hi, were you able to run it? getting the same error
